How do I remove white background in Picker.Item React Native?
There is still white background/line after I set color on Picker.Item
white line on top and bottom Picker.Item
The code :
  <Picker.Item
     label="Indonesian Rupiah (IDR)"
     value="IDR"
     style={styles.pickerItem}
     />
   <Picker.Item
     label="US Dollar (USD)"
     value="USD"
     style={styles.pickerItem}
     />

// the styles 
 pickerItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#665c54",
    color: "#fbf1c7",
    fontFamily: "PlusJakartaSans",
    margin: 90,
  },

I have tried adding backgroundColor: "#665c54", on the Picker.Item's style but there is still white line on there.

hi @Samuel what picker library are you using, that would help others know how to resolve your issue
